# AppJS --harmony issue?

Tags: javascript, node.js, command

I'm using msvc and have nodejs tools setup in it. Fairly new to node.js but all the other npm packages i've simply installed via command line or through nodejs tools and they have worked. AppJS however gives me the error when I call require('appjs').

> throw new Error('AppJS requires Node is run with the --harmony command
>   line)

Anyone know how to fix this? I get this error even when calling my script from command line doing

```
node --harmony app.js
```

Actual code

```
var serialPortLib = require("serialport");
var appjs = require('appjs');

var serialPort = new serialPortLib.SerialPort("COM13",{
    baudrate : 250000,
    parser : serialPortLib.parsers.readline('\n')
});

serialPort.on('open', function () { console.log('open'); serialPort.write("Sup!\n");});
serialPort.on('data',function(data){ console.log(data);})
```